# Display 1 no cameras rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, scene

One of my team members just cloned my unity project which was working fine on my pc(unity 5.5) where as it is displaying "Display 1 no cameras rendering" error in the scene on my teammate's pc(unity 5.4).

We are using a git repository and this is the first time we have encountered this problem.

Another thing we just noticed is that there are place holders for all the objects that were part of hierarchy(on my system). For some reason there names are not getting displayed, but when when you select the area, something seems to be selected.

Can someone please help us solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One of my team members just cloned my unity project which was working
>   fine on my pc(**unity 5.5**) where as it is displaying "Display 1 no
>   cameras rendering" error in the scene on my teammate's pc(**unity
>   5.4**)

Take a moment and look at the words in bold. You can't do that.

You shouldn't try to open a Unity project made with higher Unity version with lower Unity version. This applies to most software too. What's happening is that Unity added new feature and changed some of Unity's binary saved data in **Unity 5.5** that **Unity 5.4** doesn't have.

When you load a project from **Unity 5.5** in **Unity 5.4**, it won't be able to understand those new features leading to weird behavior such as the one he's having.

Your teammate will have to update to **Unity 5.5** in order to load the Project made with **Unity 5.5**.

Comment: While it does make sense to load projects with the same version of Unity, keep note that the error of "Display 1 no cameras rendering" is a change that occurred in Unity 5.5, where it now requires a camera, even on a scene that may only render fixed widgets like a Menu scene.

Comment: @Min If I focused on this error instead of what OP is doing wrong, OP wouldn't be able to solve this issue as there are other problems that will also appear such as lost references. It is better if the-same version is used to solve this. The rest of your comment about camera requirement is wrong. It's not required. What you see is just a warning to help new Unity users out. You can easily disable that warning.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times you downvote it. It's tailored  to fix OP's specific issue and it did and will still be here.

Comment: Hey, it's awesome that you're helping the community. Don't take my response offensively or as an attack. The challenge is that this problem is the result that pops up when searching for "Display 1 no cameras rendering" and this answer doesn't actually solve the problem. Perhaps you could also amend the answer to say for others who are specifically seeing that error to "right click" the game tab and disable the warning as demonstrated in the following url https://forum.unity.com/threads/no-camera-rendering-message-with-5-4-0p1.425533/

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue with "Display 1 no cameras rendering".

After a quick look around the interface, I clicked on my **main camera** and in the **Camera** area of the **Inspector** panel, I saw that my **Target Display** was set to "Display 4". Not sure how it got there, but changing that back to "Display 1" fixed the problem for me.

Comment: *facepalm* me too

Comment: I have the same warning when it is on display1

Comment: I have 4 cameras and can only two of them to render. My build is setup for android and the cameras are missing the display selection in the inspector. I have spent 4 hours trying to get this resolved. I havent seen any other posts with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you code and setting don't have other error，I guess you right-click on the `gamewindow`

Just the `Game`，cancel the warn `if----`

OK，just it.

Sorry，My English is not good enough.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've tried to format your answer in order to improve the readibility. Just check if it's still the one you want to give. Don't worry about your English. Most SO users aren't native speakers.

Comment: ok，3Q，I just say  The nature of the problem isnt the code error，or no other reason than that different version

Comment: This is actually a good answer, just poorly translated. What he means is, right click the Game window and click "Warn if No Cameras Rendering" to turn off that setting. The warning will go away! :)

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue , undoing all the steps until the last correct function , i found i erase the main camera without take care.